ListBox's ColumnCount not available in WindowsFormApp VisualStudio
For some strange reason, I cannot find "ColumnCount" property for my listbox in WindowsForm (.NET Framework), in Visual Studio.
When I tried to find a solution to specifying the number of columns for my listbox, the solution is largely about specifying the ColumnCount property.
However, when I type in listBox1.ColumnCount, I get the error message "CS1061: 'ListBox'does not contain a definition for 'ColumnCount'..."
I have tried removing Visual Studio and re-installing it, but it doesn't help.
Is anyone getting the same trouble as me ?

why do you think re-installing visual studio would fix this? next time refer to the WindowsForms documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Don't confuse WinForms ListBoxes with Access ListBoxes where you can indeed specify a ColumnCount! On the other hand you can override OnDrawItem in WinForms and display about anything you wish (including multiple columns and icons, colored text, etc.)

Hi @Piglet, thanks for your comment. It's not that I thought re-installing would fix the issue. But I've read some cases, where for strange reasons, certain things throw errors or "does not work" and again, for some strange reasons, re-installing fixed this.
In this case, I did not know what was the issue. Hence I was mentioning that I've already tried the "re-install" issue, in order to remove such suggestion (in case someone suggests it)

Hi @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks for your comment, I see where I had confused myself !

If I could divide the "accept as answer" to two portions, I would have shared it between Oliver and Piglet (with answer given below, not the comment here).
This is because the reason for my question, being in this way, turns out it was due to a confusion which needed to have been addressed and the verification that ListBox does not have ColumnCount helped. (I was thinking ColumnCount does not exist, but it "seemed" like programmers were talking about it as if ColumnCount did exist as a property. As a newbie, this causes confusion.).
I hope this post helps other newbies out there too !

System.Windows.Forms.ListBox does not have a ColumnCount property. That's why you can't find / use it.
A ListBox will only display multiple colums to avoid vertical scrolling if MultiColumn property is true.
If you want to display data in multiple columns consider using a ListView or DataGridView control.

Hi Piglet, for SQL related tables, would you recommend ListView or DataGridView ?
Microsoft recommends DataGridView but I've seen some programmers who recommend ListView, because it seems user-friendly.

Using ColumnWidth, ItemHeight, Listbox.Height, and Listbox.Width you can calculate the Column Count. Divide Listbox.Height by ItemHeight to see how many items can be displayed vertically. Then divide Listbox.Width by ColumnWidth to see how many items can be displayed horizontally. Count how many times you can subtract the vertical item count from your total item count until you run out of items or exceed maximum horizontal item display limit.
See example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-forms-listbox-multicolumn
